# Deleting object also deletes associated material

Tags: materials, scripting

I create an object with a script. I assign it a material. When I delete the object, the material is also deleted.

Is this normal? How to I prevent the material from being deleted?

Comment: I think it's something like `bpy.data.materials['Material Name'].use_fake_user = True`. Use it when you create the material (before you delete the object). This should keep it as an active material even after you delete the object, without it entering the orphaned data stack.

Comment: I'm trying this out, thanks! ... It looks like its working!

Comment: @S'rCat FYI Blender uses a "Fake User" system where data is automatically put in the trash can if it isn't used by another object or another type of data in the blend file. If you want to retain the data in the file even without anything else using it, you must set it to "Use Fake User"